# Displaying Rows of HTML Elements in Vertical Rows

Tags: php, html, sorting

I want to show a list of categories in my Virtuemart webshop vertically sorted the same way as shown in this demonstration:
http://www.inkplant.com/code/mysql-vertical-sort.php

So I borrowed the code:

```
    <?php
$cols = 4; //number of columns, you can set this to any positive integer
$values = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM states ORDER BY name");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$rows_per_col = ceil($numrows / $cols);
for ($c=1;$c<=$cols;$c++) { $values['col_'.$c] = array(); }
$c = 1;
$r = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $values['col_'.$c][$r] = stripslashes($row['name']);
    if ($r == $rows_per_col) { $c++; $r = 1; } else { $r++; }
}
echo "<table>" ;
for ($r=1;$r<=$rows_per_col;$r++) {
    echo "<tr>" ;
    for ($c=1;$c<=$cols;$c++) { echo "<td>".$values['col_'.$c][$r]."</td>" ; }
    echo "</tr>" ;
}
echo "</table>" ;
unset($values);
?>
```

I then tried to modify it in my Virtuemart category template file with this result:

```
<?php
$cols = 3; //number of columns, you can set this to any positive integer
$values = array();

$numrows = $precounterdigit;

$rows_per_col = ceil($numrows / $cols);
for ($c=1;$c<=$cols;$c++) { $values['col_'.$c] = array(); }
$c = 1;
$r = 1;
foreach ( $this->category->children as $category ) {
$catname = $category->category_name;
$caturl = JRoute::_ ( 'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_category_id=' . $category->virtuemart_category_id );
$values['col_'.$c][$r] = '<div class="category floatleft'.$category_cellwidth.'">
<div class="spacer"><h2>
                            <a href="'.$caturl.'" title="'.$catname.'">
                            '.$catname.'<br /></a></h2>
                                    </div></div>';  

    if ($r == $rows_per_col) { $c++; $r = 1; } else { $r++; }
}
echo '<div class="tablediv">' ;
for ($r=1;$r<=$rows_per_col;$r++) {
    echo '<div class="row">' ;
    for ($c=1;$c<=$cols;$c++) { echo $values['col_'.$c][$r]; }
    echo '</div>' ;
}
echo '</div>' ;
unset($values);
?>
```

It actually shows perfectly in the category view if the number of categories are dividable by 3 or dividable by 3 -1. Meaning that it shows correctly if there are 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12 etc... categories on the page.

If the number of categories equals a number that is dividable by 3 +1 then it shows in a weird way..

Here is an example of how it shows when there are 9 categories:

Cat1 | Cat4 | Cat7 
Cat2 | Cat5 | Cat8 
Cat3 | Cat6 | Cat9 

Here is an example of how it shows when there are 8 categories:

Cat1 | Cat4 | Cat7 
Cat2 | Cat5 | Cat8 
Cat3 | Cat6 |

And here is an example of how it shows when there are 7 categories:
Cat1 | Cat4 | Cat7 
Cat2 | Cat5 | Cat3 
Cat6 |

I really cannot figure this one out, so I hope someone can help me a little bit here..

Comment: i think this is a css problem, can you show the generate html for your  table div?

Comment: You are correct. I found out that my problem could be fixed with some minor css tweaks on the "row" class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this, Sure you can change cols and rows.

```
<?php //user210424 
$cols = 3;
$rows = 3;
$j = 0;
$array = array("ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE");

for($i=1; $i<=$cols; $i++) {
echo "<div class='col' style='float:left;'>";
    for($j; $j<$rows*$i; $j++) {
        echo "<div class='row'>".$array[$j]."</div>";
    }
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I just found out that my code was actually flawless. I just needed to tweak a little CSS. Specifically I applied width: 100%; and
display: table; to the "row" class.