# Convert mysql table from vertical to horizontal

Tags: mysql

I want to do something like this in mysql

I have a table

```
id   key               value 
001  connection_days    2
001  seniority          A
002  connection_days    15
002  seniority          A++
....
```

And I want to create a table based on this like

```
id  connection_days  seniority
001      2              A
002      15             A++
```

Does anyone know how to achevie this? Thanks

Comment: this technic is called pivot table, there are a lot of useful informations out there, just do a quick google or have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this question. It's already answered.

[Displaying Rows of HTML Elements in Vertical Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115719/displaying-rows-of-html-elements-in-vertical-rows)

Have a good day!